# Express.JS and Node-MSSQL select error: Invalid Column name on any value that isn't an int

Tags: node.js, express, where-clause, tedious

I think the table I'm trying to query isn't normalized (not my dataset). Whenever my where clause includes a value that is not a number I get the error below. It's as if the value of the where clause is confused with the column name itself. Now if I change the column to a field that only contains numbers, it executes without error. Any idea as to why this is happening?

```
  name: 'ERROR',
  event: 'errorMessage',
  number: 207,
  state: 1,
  class: 16,
  message: "Invalid column name 'somestring'.",
  serverName: 'server1234\\SQLEXPRESS',
  procName: '',
  lineNumber: 1
```

````
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

 var sql = require("mssql");

 // config for your database
 var config = {
     user: 'username',
     password: 'password',
     server: 'server1234',
     database: 'dbname1234'
 };

 // connect to your database
 sql.connect(config, function (err) {

     if (err) console.log(err);

     // create Request object
     var request = new sql.Request();

     // query to the database and get the records
     request.query('select * from dbo.recordset3 where column4=somestring', function (err, recordset) {

         if (err) console.log(err)

         // send records as a response
         res.send(recordset);

     });
 });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
 console.log('Server is running..');
});```
````

Comment: You need to put somestring in quotes or mysql thinks you're referencing a column. So your query should be: 

`request.query('select * from dbo.recordset3 where column4="somestring"', function (err, recordset) {`

Comment: Thanks Mark! This is what I thought initially. However - I was getting results with ints without using the quotes. For instance, when I used another field that had numerical values (int) it would return the result regardless. The quotes also need to be escaped or it will not work. For record results with datatypes that are not int - it requires escaped quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! when using where you need to use escaped single quotes.

`where column4 = \'somestring\'`

Answer (score 0):

```
request.query(('select * from users WHERE username=' + '\'' + req.body.username + '\''), function (err, recordset) {
```

Answer (score 0):

U should use `request.input` function to pass values to query to avoid sql injection attempts.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#sql-injection

```
    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    //use request.input 
    request.input('column4',sql.VarChar,"somestring");

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from dbo.recordset3 where column4=@column4', function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
             // send records as a response
             res.send(recordset);
         });
```